# Python Script cannot write into file from Cronjob. But it can when I run it manually

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

Im Trying to run some run python3 script that gets some data from Ubuntu 16 and 18 machine and write it into file.

For some reason when I run it manually it works but from a crontab it isn't working.

I tried those solution from here:

1. cd to the working directory on the crontab.
2. Tried to run the cron as root and gave permissions to the py file.
3. I tried to run bash script that execute this py script but still it didn't work.
4. I tried to move the output to a log file and it shows me onlt the last part the the script done. (as i mentioned down)

5.I tried to grep cron from the services and i got the MTA error and also fixed it and it still didn't work.

6.When im just create a py script that print regular string into file it works. but this script isn't work.

**Part of My code:**

```
     else:
    txtFile = open("/home/user/knifeStatus.txt","w+")
    os.chdir("/etc/chef")
    os.system(sslfetch) **#until this part it do it correctly**
    knifeLnxResult = str(os.popen(knifeLnx).read())
    knifeResultTime = knifeLnxResult[0:10]
```

**After this part ends it does some calculation and then im calling the next function to write it into the file.**

```
fileCreator(str(chefDaysPass),str(chefHourPass))

#Function to creates and edit the text file.
def fileCreator(chefDaysPass , chefHourPass):
    textInside = ("Last Chef run completed at: {} | {}") 
    textInside = textInside.format(str(chefDaysPass),str(chefHourPass))
    txtFile.write(textInside)
    txtFile.close()
    print("Knife File Created succesfully")
```

My crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/chef/ && /usr/bin/python3 /var/chef/Knife_Status.py > /var/chef/cronOut.log
```

Any suggestions? **Really need some help**.

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of that line of your crontab to ensure that stderr goes into the logfile as well as stdout, and then check the logfile after it has run.